# Groups, neutral elements and uniqueness

Tags: group-theory

consider $x \circ z = x$

suppose for a set G that at first glance fullfill the group axioms, besides the neutral element one which is in question because:

$\exists e\forall x$ with $x \circ e = x$,

but also $\forall x_i\exists y_i$ with $x_i \circ y_i = x_i$ and $y_j\ne y_i\ne e$, with $i\ne j$

now is $e$ the neutral element, despite that it's not the unique solution for $x \circ z = x$, but the only one that generally applies to all elements ?

Comment: ....What....?? I feel dizzy...

Comment: Also http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Linux, you'll have to be more specific before we can help. Elements of $G$ do not map anything to anything else; that is what functions do, and the elements of $G$ are not (necessarily) functions. Also, it will be clearer for people if you write $x O e = x$ as $xe=x$. And it will be clearer if you consistently use lowercase letters to refer to elements of mathematical structures. And, you want to make your question really STAND OUT. e.g. Start a new line. Write QUESTION. Then write your question is clear English. See what I mean? You have to help us help you.

Comment: in definition a group is a set with an operation, that fullfills certain criteria http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @LinuxNoob1337 Indeed so, yet it is *the operation* (a binary one) that does the mapping, not the elements of the assumed group.

Comment: so the ordered pairs (a,e) and (e,a) a,e element G, together with the operation that defines G, are mapped to a, but honestly, in every day noone writes O(a,b), everyone uses a O b, if you can tell me how a O b = c is said in everyday english math then that would help resolve the confusion

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you mean, but ....

If $G$ is a group, every element $g\in G$ defines a *translation*, i.e. a function
$$
\tau_g:G\rightarrow G, \qquad \tau_g(x)=gx, \forall x\in G.
$$
When you take $g=e=e_G$ (the neutral element in $G$), the translation $\tau_e$ is simply the identity on $G$, since $\tau_g(x)=ex=x$.

But if $g\neq e$, there's no $x\in G$ such that $\tau_g(x)=x$. Indeed, if you had $gx=x$ for some $x\in G$ you could appeal to the cancellation property (which holds unconditionally in groups) and conclude that $g=e$.

Does this answer your question?